# Information security career

Tags: career

I am a graduate software engineer ( Bachelor degree ), now working as software engineer.  I am thinking about following a career in information security.
My question is:

- Should I follow a master degree in this area?
- or would it be enough to take the required certifications available on the market?

Could someone please recommend me what certificates are better ?

Thank you!

Comment: There are various careers within infosec: malware analyst, pen tester, forensics, auditor, manager, etc. Any particular idea where you want to go? Also, do you prefer big or small companies. Big companies love certifications, while small ones care more about competency.

Comment: If you search on this site for "carrer" or "student" you will find tons of similar questions. Maybe you study them first.

Comment: There is no way that we will be able to answer this for you. Each industry and country and position level have their own standards. This is the sort of question you need to ask the companies in the area where you live in an informational interview. The one thing I will say is that certs and degrees matter far less than being able to show a history of skill and competence.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, IT is one of those areas where it's much more important to show your work than your papers. A lot of people who are good at school are average when it actually comes to solving real-world problems. And i would argue even a lot more who are geniuses at a keyboard don't do well in school. [A lot of companies realise this, so they look at what you actually do](https://medium.com/always-be-coding/four-steps-to-google-without-a-degree-8f381aa6bd5e#.othc9pfov)

So my answer? a good github page, a CVE number or a some other impressive responsible disclosures on your name will get you further than any formal certification will beyond what you have now. Unless your goal is to go into academics.

Answer (score -2):

I've worked in the industry for close to 14 yrs now with varying roles of Software Development and QA primarily in the security domain.

If you're looking for your first job breakthrough, it doesn't matter if you have a graduate engineering degree or a post-graduate degree as long as you know "stuff" - seriously - if you're able to impress your potential employer, they wont care if you're a BS or MS holder.

Now how do you get knowing your **stuff**? (*In no particular order, except #1*)

1. Get hands dirty. Start doing it!
2. Few important languages to start for information security - C, Python, PERL, JavaScript, HTML
3. Know OOPS concepts - if you know Java/C++, consider it bonus!
4. Data Structures and few important algorithms
5. OSI model and OWASP concepts
6. Virtualization (VmWare, Virtual Box) and Containers (Docker, Kubernetes)
7. Penetration testing and frameworks (MetaSploit, Kali Linux)
8. Know the cloud - AWS, Azure and GCP. It's not a fad anymore.
9. Get certified to "prove" this as well after you've practiced. Don't pass exams by brain-dumps - you will get a certificate but zero knowledge

**What Certs to get:**

1. CCNA - THE #1 beginner level vendor-neutral cert for networking.
2. RHCE - THE #1 beginner level vendor-neutral cert for Linux.
3. CEH - You should aim for this to become a security specialist.
4. AWS Certified Solutions Architect
5. CISSP (maybe after you've learned sufficiently enough as it requires min 4 yrs experience. You can still become an associate though)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this is a nice answer. I also like to start in this field (currently 3rd semester in B.Sc Computer Science) and like to know if these languages are a must have, as I'm currently only "fluent" with php, c#, HTML and JS. Also, what do you think about the Linux + and Security + certs?

Comment: @TechTreeDev I know many competent security pros who do not have any certs. Certs should prove what you already know how to do.

Comment: @runcyhere CCNA and RHCE are *vendor-neutral*?

Comment: I'll be honest, I've never heard any security engineer take the CEH seriously.

Comment: The "get to know your stuff" section is decent, but the section on certs is perplexing. This would be a better answer if that section were simply gone.

Comment: The only certifications that I am aware that security engineers take particularly seriously are OSCP and OSCE. There might be others but I'm not aware of them. The CISSP is required if you want to work in the federal government, from my understanding.